# Javascript used to Compare Text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I have used a jQuery from picadiff to compare < p> in my < td>.

I have followed the steps accordingly but I am not sure as to why it is not showing up accordingly.

Here are my codes in HTML for razor (cshtml):

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.picadiff').picadiff({
                leftContent: $('.leftForm td').val(),
                rightContent: $('.rightForm td').val()
            });
        });
        $(".picadiff").picadiff();
    });
```

```html
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/diff_match_patch.js"></script>

    <!-- Helper Classes -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/diff_match_patch_extended.js"></script>

    <!-- Widget -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/picadiff.js"></script>

  

    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/styles/jquery.picadiff.css">
    <script src="~/Scripts/picadiff.js"></script>

    <table class="picadiff">
        <tr>
            <th>Header:</th>
            <td style="width:45%" class="leftForm form">
                foreach (string x in @displayarray1)
                {
                    <p>@x</p>
                }
            </td>
            <td style="width:45%" class="rightForm form">
                foreach (string x in @displayarray2)
                {
                    <p>@x</p>
                }
            </td>
        <tr>
    </table>
```

May I know where have I gone wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Overall my end goal is to have website that compares and displays the result on a table which highlights the similarities and differences. Which is similar to gsmarena.

[image: Sample of GSM Arena's comparison table]

Comment: Why do you tag this with C#? I can see only JS code here:\

Comment: hi, because i am using razor which is cshtml to code this. will remove the tag then

Comment: I mean, are you sure this may be relevant to razor? As I can see, you have a problem with JS code, so, if I where you, instead of JS+Razor, I better post JS+"Razor-Generated-HTML", so more people can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong jQuery function. According to the jQuery documentation,

> The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.

You are calling this function on a table cell, which does not technically have a "value." What you're probably looking for is `.text()` - assuming you only want the text and not the inner html (as your text is wrapped in `<p>` tags). Check out the documentation for more info

[.val() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

[.text() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/)